# How do you refer to plural nouns?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I'm wondering how I can refer to a plural noun in the following sentence.

> I lost my glasses. I need to get **one**.

(Talking about a single pair of glasses)

Since "glasses" is plural, I assume **one** doesn't suit here, but I don't know any appropriate alternative.

Comment: You need to get *new ones*.

Comment: Or I need to get some more, or a new pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

> I need to get some.
>
> I need to get new ones.
>
> I need to get a pair.

Either refer to them as plural, since you established them as a plural, or explicitly refer to the pair as a new singular item.